# low speed on client server programming using c

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client-server

I am not an expert in C. I am using a client server code which will be sending 2-32 bit numbers from server(running in a remote system::a Linux system running inside an FPGA) to client program running in PC. Both are connected to a router using Ethernet cables. I was expecting at least a speed of 150k+, but barely i am getting 1k. There is a read function inside my client program(in a while loop) is the cause of delay.
So can anybody suggest anything to speed up my data transfer ?
My intention is high speed real time data transfer between server and client.

My both client and server programs are running successfully.  But at low speed.

My server code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void)
{
  int listenfd = 0,connfd = 0; 
  int count1=0;
  int count2=100;
  char chr_count1[50];//increase 50 if you going for more than 32 bit
  char chr_count2[50];// 
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  char sendBuff[50];  
  listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  printf("socket retrieve success\n");

  memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
  memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff));

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;    
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);    

  bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));

  if(listen(listenfd, 10) == -1){
      printf("Failed to listen\n");
      return -1;
  } 
  connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL ,NULL); // accept awaiting request   
  while(1)
    {  
      count1 = count1+1;
      count2 = count2+1;
      sprintf(chr_count1, "%d\n\t",count1);
      sprintf(chr_count2, "%d\n",count2);  
      strcpy(sendBuff, chr_count1);
      write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff));
      strcpy(sendBuff, chr_count2);
      write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff));
    } 

  return 0;
}
```

My client code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void)
{
  int sockfd = 0,n = 0;
  char recvBuff[50];
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

  memset(recvBuff, '0' ,sizeof(recvBuff));
  if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))< 0)
    {
      printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
      return 1;
    }

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.56.17.39");

  if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
    {
      printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
      return 1;
    } 
  while(1)
    {
      n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1);
      recvBuff[n] = 0;
      if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF)
    {
      printf("\n Error : Fputs error");
    }
      printf("\n");
    }

  if( n < 0)
    {
      printf("\n Read Error \n");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

I think write and read functions are responsible for the lower speed, so how can in increase the speed. will read and write functions always have this bottle neck or is it because of my system requirements. (I am using an embedded command shell in my client side)

Comment: It probably won't make a difference, but can you try `fsync(connfd)` after your second `write`? `fsync` shouldn't matter in your case, but just in case.

Comment: What do you achieve using `strcpy(sendBuff, chr_count1);  write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff));` over just `write(connfd, chr_count1, strlen(chr_count1))`?

Comment: You could use `fdopen(connfd)` to obtain a `FILE *` `stdio` file handle for the connected socket; then just use `fprintf` to send output. The benefit is that the stream will do block buffering and call `write` in buffer-sized chunks.

Comment: @Kaz :: I am not that fluent in c. I got a program from internet and then made changes for my requirements. anyway your first suggestion is same as my program right. I think it wont make any difference in speed. so can you please give some more information about your second suggestion ? I think I need something much much **faster**

Comment: Many things may play major roles in your case e.g. the load on client/server machines, the specs of those machines.. Actually your code looks like has serious issues like the while loop in your server code which does not pause at all, my suggestion is to specify your requirements well i.e. specify the bandwidth you really need and see whither Linux/Windows machines can meet that bandwidth and then start your measurements again and analyse the results.

Comment: @muaz yes I don't want to pause the while loop, once its starts, it should be continues. I will implement the pause thing by sending something from client to server, that's the later part. how can I can the bandwidth of the server, can you please give any tips ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the properties and limits of your server, may be could you save a bit of computing power (not sure it is relevant in this case).

```
int len=sprintf(sendBuff, "%d\n\t%d\n", ++count1, ++count);  
write(connfd, sendBuff, len);
```

`sprintf()` returns the length of the generated string (no need to recompute with `strlen()`).
Only one call to `write()` can save a system call.

How do you measure timings? Aren't the `fputs()`/`printf()` (in the client) called during timing? That could have a non negligible influence.

Comment: actually the **write** function in the server side is responsible for printing in the client side

Comment: @dipin Yes, I know that. But since it's TCP, two consecutive writes should not be considered different from one single. And you could just receive in the client but not actually print to the console what is received (during timing).